# What commands is undergoing when I right click an maven-project in eclipse and select the update project item?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

What commands is undergoing when I right click an maven-project in eclipse and select the update project item? Or is there a way to examine this?

Comment: No Maven command per se. It's M2E doing its magic that's all (so it is really Eclipse specific).

Comment: You need to view the source code of M2E plugin, you can get idea.

Comment: @Tunaki Could any of you turn your comment to an answer?

Comment: Or @Simze since your comments mean the same! :)